# Mongoose-Encryption error after push to Heroku

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, encryption, environment-variables

thank you for spending time looking at this problem.

Firstly, when I test this in localhost:3000 it works, there are no errors and I can seamlessly run my application, encrypt my password and push it to MongoDB.

Then, the problem sets in with Heroku after I do my git commits and push it through. The app does not start and crashes. and comes up with errors that I have scoured the internet for and even those who had problems, and I have completely copied there solutions, still have the same error.

**heroko logs --tail (hyper console):**

```
throw new Error('must provide either options.secret or both options.encryptionKey and options.signingKey');
```

however I do provide these and I like I have said, I have scoured and observed the internet:

!!.dotenv has been installed as a node package!!

**My server JS:**

```
    require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const tytyDigitalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  email: String,
  verified: Boolean
});

var secret = process.env.SOME_LONG_UNGUESSABLE_STRING;
tytyDigitalSchema.plugin(encrypt, { secret: secret ,  encryptedFields: ['Password']});

const Users = mongoose.model("user", tytyDigitalSchema);
```

**My .env file**

```
SOME_LONG_UNGUESSABLE_STRING=Thisisa32bytebasestring
```

**Lastly, incase it helps, my .gitignore:**
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Node.gitignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has solved it:
Heroku does not read your .env file as you .gitignore it.
Instead in Heroku (application screen), you will see a settings page and a config vars panel, which asks for a key and a value, these fields represent our .env file. So my KEY would have to be:

```
SOME_LONG_UNGUESSABLE_STRING
```

and my value would be:

```
Thisisa32bytebasestring
```

This will now enable to site to be built correctly and work.